# 'ErrorException' with message Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel. I'm trying to display errors in my view but I'm getting an error:

> ErrorException with message 'Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Here is my error logic:

```php
@foreach(['success' => 'check', 'info' => 'exclamation-circle', 'warning' => 'warning', 'danger' => 'ban'] as $type => $icon )
    @if (Session::has($type))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ $type }} fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></a>
            <i class="fa fa-{{ $icon }}"></i> {{ Session::get( $type ) }}
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $index => $message)
        <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp; {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your view code looks fine, so the problem might originate somewhere else (perhaps you're passing data to the view in a format different than you're expecting), so please edit your question to include a full stack trace of the error.